# Why Apache ActiveMQ isn’t good for .NET developers?

Tags: c#, java, jms, activemq-classic

According to [this article](http://blog.goyello.com/2009/09/07/why-apache-activemq-isnt-good-for-net-developers/) even though Apache ActiveMQ supports .NET, this feature is limited only to basic client operations. Apache ActiveMQ does not give access to manipulate ActiveMQ broker, persistent store or transports.

I don't really understand what prevents Apache ActiveMQ to present same features for .NET client as for Java client: is it because they "forget", they don't want, they can't but could in the future?

Comment: ActiveMQ was written in Java so it has better support for Java.  Perhaps you are looking for a messaging service which was written for .NET?

Comment: My projects can be in both world that's why I was looking at it :)

Comment: I suggest you use the broker from the Java side and use the clients from Java/C# as I believe this is how it was designed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ActiveMQ .NET clients support all the features that Java clients enjoy.  It even comes with WCF integration! About the only tricky feature that Java clients can use which would be tricky to get working on .NET is that Java client can [boot up a ActiveMQ server in the same process as the client](http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-embed-a-broker-inside-a-connection.html).  The need to do that is not very common.  If you really need to do it, you might want to try running the ActiveMQ server in [IKVM](http://www.ikvm.net/).